# How to fix 'Error in if (p_change[j] == dat[i, 1]) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed' in a loop?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, if-statement

I am new to R. I am running a loop which basically compares the values contained in a vector (**p_change**) with the values in a column of a data frame (**dat**, column *IndicatorID*, more specifically). In case *IndicatorID* and the number in **p_change** coincides, I want the value on *standardised* to be subtracted by one (on the same row).
This is a sample of the vector (**p_change**):

```
p_change <- c(30101,92901,92031,90630,90282,10401)
```

The data frame (**dat**) to which it is compared is as follows:

```
IndicatorID IndicatorName                                          AreaName             standardised variance
        <int> <chr>                                                  <chr>                       <dbl>    <dbl>
1       10401 1.04 - First time entrants to the youth justice system Hartlepool                  0.601   13478.
2       10401 1.04 - First time entrants to the youth justice system Middlesbrough               0.481   13478.
3       10401 1.04 - First time entrants to the youth justice system Redcar and Cleveland        0.773   13478.
4       10401 1.04 - First time entrants to the youth justice system Stockton-on-Tees            0.732   13478.
5       10401 1.04 - First time entrants to the youth justice system Darlington                  0.545   13478.
6       10401 1.04 - First time entrants to the youth justice system Halton                      0.353   13478.
```

The for loop that I am running is this one:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(dat)) {
  for (j in 1:length(p_change)) {
    if (p_change[j]==dat[i,1]) {
      dat[i,4] <- 1-dat[i,4] # Subtraction of a unit (polarity change)
    } else {
      i = i+1
    }
  }
}
```

However, after running it, it throws me the following error 'Error in if (p_change[j] == dat[i, 1]) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed'. I was wondering if you spot the glitch that causes the error.
Thanks!

Comment: (1) Please do post images of data: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3358272 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). It is much better to give unambiguous data such as with the output of `dput(head(dat))`; there could be many things that cause problems, not all of them are discernible when shown as an image or on the console. (My guess: your comparison includes an invalid number, see for example `if (NA) 1 else 2`.)

Answer (score 0):

The ordering of the for loops is incorrect. Firstly, the code should loop over the vector and then over the data frame in question.

```
for (i in 1:length(p_change)) {
  for (j in 1:nrow(dat)) {
    if (p_change[j]==dat[i,1]) {
      dat[i,4] <- 1-dat[i,4] # Subtraction of a unit (polarity change)
    } else {
      i = i+1
    }
  }
}
```